# Python append multiple lists with same columns headers

Tags: python

I am using an NBA package called nba_py to pull certain boxscore information (this is one example). Once the package is inserted, you pull information like so:

`from nba_py import game
print(game.Boxscore('0021700001').team_stats())`

Inside the quotes is a unique game ID - each game has two teams (rows) with column headers. I need to append every game of the season to create a master table with all boxscores (among other) information. I have tried several things that haven't worked:

```
boxscore = game.BoxscoreFourFactors("0021700001").sql_team_four_factors()
for i in range (21700002, 21701231):
    boxscore.append(game.BoxscoreFourFactors('00' + str(i)).sql_team_four_factors())
```

This ^ only shows initial table result and none of the appended. If I start with blank list and append each "table" to blank list the list shows up as a table, table, table instead of column headers with each team per game info listed below.

```
colList = ['GAME_ID', 'TEAM_ID', 'TEAM_NAME' .... ]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = colList)
i = 0
for x in range(21700001, 21700005):
    new_entry = game.BoxscoreFourFactors("00" + str(x)).sql_team_four_factors()
    df.loc[i] = new_entry
    i = i + 1
```

I have also tried creating a datframe w/ pandas and adding entries using df.loc[i] = new entry but the "entry" is technically 3 rows (headers + one row per team) instead of single row so I get error "cannot set row with mismatched columns". I alos tried df.concat with no success... Can anyone help?

If curious here is nba_py: https://github.com/seemethere/nba_py